# Input array in scala

Tags: arrays, scala, input

I am new to scala, how to read numbers of integer given in one line? For example:

```
5
10 20 30 40 50
```

I want to store it in an array. How to split the input and store it in array?

Single integer can be read by `readInt()` method and then I read input using `readLine()`, but don't know how to split and store it in array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
val s = readLine
val a: Array[Int] = s.split(" ").map(_.toInt)
```

or 
   `val a = readLine.split(" ").map(_.toInt)` ;)

Answer (score 4):

Without comment:

```
scala> val in = "10 20 30 40 50"
in: String = 10 20 30 40 50

scala> (in split " ")
res0: Array[String] = Array(10, 20, 30, 40, 50)

scala> (in split " ") map (_.toInt)
res1: Array[Int] = Array(10, 20, 30, 40, 50)
```

With comment, I really want `fscanf`:

```
scala> val f"$i%d" = "10"
<console>:7: error: macro method f is not a case class, nor does it have an unapply/unapplySeq member
       val f"$i%d" = "10"
           ^
```

But it occurs to me that for your use case, you want a simple syntax to scan for ints.

Without having to repeat myself:

```
scala> val r = """(\d+)""".r
r: scala.util.matching.Regex = (\d+)

scala> r findAllMatchIn in
res2: Iterator[scala.util.matching.Regex.Match] = non-empty iterator

scala> .toList
res3: List[scala.util.matching.Regex.Match] = List(10, 20, 30, 40, 50)
```

https://issues.scala-lang.org/browse/SI-8268

Comment: You could always contribute the code for the fscanf... :) After all, the f interpolator _is_ a macro.